# Mysql cluster 7.2.2 ignored settings and TABLE IS FULL error

Tags: mysql, config, cluster-computing

This is my `my.cnf` settings

```
[mysqld]
ndbcluster
#engine_condition_pushdown=0
optimizer_switch=engine_condition_pushdown=off

# IP address of the cluster management node
ndb-connectstring=127.0.0.1

[mysql_cluster]
# IP address of the cluster management node
ndb-connectstring=127.0.0.1


[ndbd default]
NoOfReplicas= 2
MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations= 10000
DataMemory= 320M
IndexMemory= 96M
TimeBetweenWatchDogCheck= 30000
DataDir= /usr/local/mysql-cluster-gpl-7.2.2-osx10.6-x86_64/mysql-cluster
MaxNoOfOrderedIndexes= 512



[MYSQLD DEFAULT]

[NDB_MGMD DEFAULT]

[TCP DEFAULT]

# Section for the cluster management node
[NDB_MGMD]
# IP address of the management node (this system)
id=1
HostName=127.0.0.1


# Section for the storage nodes
[NDBD]
# IP address of the first storage node
id=2
HostName=127.0.0.1
DataDir= /usr/local/mysql-cluster-gpl-7.2.2-osx10.6-x86_64/mysql-cluster


[NDBD]
# IP address of the second storage node
id=3
HostName=127.0.0.1
DataDir= /usr/local/mysql-cluster-gpl-7.2.2-osx10.6-x86_64/mysql-cluster2

# one [MYSQLD] per storage node
[MYSQLD]
[MYSQLD]
```

I set data memory 320M and when I run script to fill table it stop with error 'table blabla is full'. 
I try to run `ndb_mgmd` with `-f` option and with path of configuration file. 
I copy this file in mysql-cluster folder with name `config.ini` but without result.

I got:

```
ndb_mgm> ALL REPORT MEMORYUSAGE
Node 2: Data usage is 100%(2560 32K pages of total 2560)
Node 2: Index usage is 74%(1741 8K pages of total 2336)
Node 3: Data usage is 100%(2560 32K pages of total 2560)
Node 3: Index usage is 74%(1741 8K pages of total 2336)
```

2560*32K=80M. 80M is like default mysql cluster settings.

Comment: Have you restarted ndb_mgmd with either the --initial or --reload option to refetch the configuration from the config file? If not, the changes in the config file will be ignored and the config will be fetched from the binary store in the config-dir.

Comment: Error while reading settings if all settings in one file. mysqld start ok. But ndb_mgmd log errors about ignored settings file because settings for mysqld he can't parse, and stop load file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solve my problem. I need to divide this config on two config files one for mysql server and put it in data/my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
ndbcluster
#engine_condition_pushdown=0
optimizer_switch=engine_condition_pushdown=off

# IP address of the cluster management node
ndb-connectstring=127.0.0.1

[mysql_cluster]
# IP address of the cluster management node
ndb-connectstring=127.0.0.1
```

And second file for cluster bundle in /mysql_cluster/config.ini folder:

```
[ndbd default]
NoOfReplicas= 2
MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations= 10000
DataMemory= 320M
IndexMemory= 96M
TimeBetweenWatchDogCheck= 30000
DataDir= /usr/local/mysql-cluster-gpl-7.2.2-osx10.6-x86_64/mysql-cluster
MaxNoOfOrderedIndexes= 512



[MYSQLD DEFAULT]

[NDB_MGMD DEFAULT]

[TCP DEFAULT]

# Section for the cluster management node
[NDB_MGMD]
# IP address of the management node (this system)
id=1
HostName=127.0.0.1


# Section for the storage nodes
[NDBD]
# IP address of the first storage node
id=2
HostName=127.0.0.1
DataDir= /usr/local/mysql-cluster-gpl-7.2.2-osx10.6-x86_64/mysql-cluster


[NDBD]
# IP address of the second storage node
id=3
HostName=127.0.0.1
DataDir= /usr/local/mysql-cluster-gpl-7.2.2-osx10.6-x86_64/mysql-cluster2

# one [MYSQLD] per storage node
[MYSQLD]
[MYSQLD]
```