# Mysql Cluster DataMemory size and storage disk option

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing, key-value

I have about 100M rows in my key-value table which is currently innodb. However I would like to move to MySQL Cluster and would like to understand how it stores data in memory and on disk.

I don't have enough RAM to fit my key-value table, so I have made it to store value data on disk with storage disk option when creating the ndb table. My DataMemory is set to 5 GB and IndexMemory is set to 2 GB. But when I start importing my data at some point it fails telling that the table is full. I have enough disk space. So how should I do? Do I understand correctly that I don't have to have RAM size bigger than my data size and that I only need to have RAM for primary key index which can be distributed in data nodes or it is incorrect?

Comment: So basically I'm asking if my.dataSize > param.DataMemory is possible with MySQL Cluster.

Comment: I think I've found it. It says in the manual that if you have text or blob data type for your on disk columns it will store the first 256 bytes of it in-memory and the rest on disk. So possibly you need to change your text to varchar, but it has it's dark side which is that varchar will use the maximum possible space on your disk.

Comment: May be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158177